# Best way to make jquery ui with typescript

Tags: jquery-ui, typescript, jquery-widgets

I'm making a jquery widget with [widget factory](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/) typed in typescript. How to provide a good intellisense without having to write .d.ts ?

ex:

```
/*mywidget.ts*/

$.widget("ui.mywidget", {
    options: {
        myoption: ""
    },
    doSomething: function () {
        this._hasDoSomething = true;
        /*do doSomething*/
    },
    hasDoSomething: function (): bool {
        return <bool>this._hasDoSomething;
    }
});

/*mywidget.d.ts*/
interface MyWidgetOptions {
    myoption: string;
}

interface MyWidget extends Widget, MyWidgetOptions {}

interface NLIB { 
    mywidget: MyWidget;
}

interface JQuery {
    mywidget(): JQuery;
    mywidget(methodName: string): JQuery;
    mywidget(options: MyWidgetOptions): JQuery;
    mywidget(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string): any;
    mywidget(optionLiteral: string, options: MyWidgetOptions): any;
    mywidget(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string, optionValue: any): JQuery;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    nlib: NLIB;
}


/// <reference path="teste.d.ts" />
$(".teste").mywidget({
    myoption: "asdadds"
});
```

Too boring to write .d.ts for each plugin. Any alternative ?

note:
If I don't include a mywidget.d.ts this code will no compile and I will not have intellisense:

```
///<reference path="path/to/jqueryui-1.9.d.ts"/>
$(".teste").mywidget({ 
    myoption: "asdadds"
});
```

/* 
compiler out: 
... the property 'mywidget' does not exist on value of type 'JQuery'
*/

Comment: I believe I share the motivation for this question.  I **love** typescript, but I wish it had a good answer for a typescript-"native" DOM manipulation library that could be extended to build out typescript-native UI widgets (like auto-complete).  I understand why the JQuery UI Widget Factory (which I also loved, pre-typescript) is a bad match here, but what more typescripty solution is possible instead?

Answer (score 11):

The [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) project on GitHub provides definition files for most of the popular JavaScript libraries.

All you need to do is download the file you need and reference it in your code like:

```
///<reference path="path/to/jqueryui-1.9.d.ts"/>
```

Comment: If I don't include a mywidget.d.ts this code will no compile and I will not have intellisense:

 ///<reference path="path/to/jqueryui-1.9.d.ts"/>
 $(".teste").mywidget({ 
  myoption: "asdadds"
 });
/* 
compiler out: 
... the property 'mywidget' does not exist on value of type 'JQuery'
*/

Comment: So your viewModel would just have something like this `///<reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts"/>`
`import * as $ from "jquery"`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want a .d.ts file, just use the declare keyword before your interface.
For an example, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16967239/1859442