# Using typescript to write jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Is it possible to and can anyone give me an example of using Typescript to write a jQuery plugin. I feel like the plugin structure would be much more maintainable and readable if plugins were written as classes, but I can't find any examples of that online. My idea is basically as follows, but I don't know if it will work.

```
class Modalify{

  constructor(public options: Object) {}

  public doSomething() {
    console.log(this.options);
  }

}

$.fn.modalify = Modalify;
```

**edit** this is not a duplicate because I am specifically looking for the es2015 way of doing this. The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585509) is using regular javascript and just trying to add typing support

Comment: It is possible and your way looks fine. However the answer to this question would be primarily opinion based and likely to generate a lot unnecessary of discussion. If you seek to improve your code you can use the codereview site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KhairulIslam see my edit. The post you tagged as the duplicate is still using es5 syntax. I am looking to use classes with jQuery plugins