# Property 'slider' does not exist on type 'JQuery' with typescript

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

how to come out of this error?

```
 jQuery(this.el.nativeElement.children[0]).slider('option', optionName, this.value);
```

**Error:**

```
file: 'file:/slider_component/slider.component.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Property 'slider' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.'
at: '85,55'
source: 'ts'
```

Comment: Ain't Slider a part of JqueryUI? maybe check https://jqueryui.com/slider/ you might not have the JqueryUI included or in the wrong order.

It will help if you create a snippet or show us your code

Comment: how to install with the typescript?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980549/best-way-to-make-jquery-ui-with-typescript

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes i have done that, but vs code shows compile error

Comment: Where id you find `slider.component.ts` or did you make it yourself?

Comment: https://github.com/matthieu-D/primefork/blob/80af31834fce49fb1ff0f0c347aca53709fe0584/components/slider/slider.ts

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this at the top of the component

```
declare let jQuery: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the jQueryUI, you can get it at http://jqueryui.com/download/

jQuery itself doesn't have the slider property

Comment: @user2280016 can you show me a little bit more code?

Comment: the function where .slider is being called

Comment: am using system.config.js is that the issue?

Comment: ngOnChanges(changes: { [key: string]: SimpleChange }) {
        if (this.initialized) {
            for (var key in changes) {
                jQuery(this.el.nativeElement.children[0]).slider('option', key, changes[key].currentValue);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: I have not worked with system.config.js yet but based on your error it seems like jQueryUI is not loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136226/discussion-between-paul-roefs-and-user2280016).

Answer (score 0):

Adding jqueryui types to your project may resolve this issue. It did for me, I was using $(".abc").tabs(), and would receive a similar error. Adding the types via npm command below resolved. Note that you execute this command in your project root using cmd/terminal

```
npm i -D @types/jqueryui
```